# How can I change a network after initialising using functional API?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network, keras

I have a rather "simple" question. When I create a network using the functional API:

```
layer2 = Dense(8, name="layer2")(layer1)
```

and then initialise it with

```
model = Model(input=..., output=...)
```

what can I do if I want to change layers afterwards? If I `.pop()` and then `.append()` a new layer, nothing changes - the output stays the same. I think this is because the output is still defined beforehand.

The exact problem I have is this: I load a pre-trained AlexNet with its weights but then I would like to retrain the last `Dense` layer for a classification task of 8 classes instead of 1000. For this I wanted to drop the last layers and re-add them.

I found a workaround ([Changing pretrained AlexNet classification in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042582/changing-pretrained-alexnet-classification-in-keras)) but I think there should be an easier way. Additionally, I dont think my workaround will work with a [GoogLeNet](https://gist.github.com/joelouismarino/a2ede9ab3928f999575423b9887abd14) so I would really love to know (or a hint) how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Model` object does not hold the weights, the layers do. You can load the weights for your model using `model.load_weights()` and then create a new layer based on the layers you have without losing the initialization of the layers.

For example:

```
model.load_weights(f)
newClassificationLayer = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(lastCnnLayer)
model = Model(input=oldInput, output=newClassificationLayer)
```

To make sure all other layers are frozen and do not get trained except for your new layer you can set `trainable=False` for each layer you want to freeze. E.g.:

```
lastCnnLayer.trainable = False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that I know that the Layers hold the weights, this makes things much easier!