# How add new class in saved keras sequential model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I have 10 class dataset with this I got 85% accuracy, got the same accuracy on a saved model.
now I want to add a new class, how to add a new class To the saved model.
I tried by deleting the last layer and train but model get overfit and in prediction every Images show same result (newly added class).

This is what I did

```
model.pop()
base_model_layers = model.output
pred = Dense(11, activation='softmax')(base_model_layers)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=pred)
# compile and fit step
```

I have trained model with 10 class I want to load the model train with class 11 data and give predictions.

Comment: You may want to freeze the other layers from training any further

Comment: @SreeramTP how to do that

Comment: I think this is similar to you issue https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/

Comment: More info regarding freezing and transfer learning can be found on this blog post https://deeplearningsandbox.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-and-fine-tuning-in-keras-and-tensorflow-to-build-an-image-recognition-94b0b02444f2

Answer (score 2):

Using the **model.pop()** method and then the **Keras Model() API** will lead you to an **error**. **The Model() API does not have the .pop() method**, so **if you want to re-train your model more than once you will have this error.**

**But the error only occurs if you, after the re-training, save the model and use the new saved model in the next re-training.**

Another very **wrong** and used approach is to use the **model.layers.pop()**. This time the problem is that function only removes the last layer in the copy it returns. So, the model still has the layer, and just the method's return does not have the layer.

I recommend the following solution:

**Admitting you have your already trained model saved in the model variable, something like:**

```py
model = load_my_trained_model_function()

# creating a new model
model_2 = Sequential()

# getting all the layers except the output one
for layer in model.layers[:-1]: # just exclude last layer from copying
    model_2.add(layer)

# prevent the already trained layers from being trained again 
# (you can use layers[:-n] to only freeze the model layers until the nth layer)
for layer in model_2.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# adding the new output layer, the name parameter is important 
# otherwise, you will add a Dense_1 named layer, that normally already exists, leading to an error
model_2.add(Dense(num_neurons_you_want, name='new_Dense', activation='softmax'))
```

**Now you should specify the compile and fit methods** to train your model and it's done:

```py
model_2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.fit trains the model
model_history = model_2.fit(x_train, y_train,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            verbose=1,
                            validation_split=0.1)
```

**EDIT:**

**Note that by adding a new output layer we do not have the weights and biases adjusted in the last training.**

Thereby we lost pretty much everything from the previous training.

**We need to save the weights and biases of the output layer of the previous training, and then we must add them to the new output layer.**

We also must think if we should let all the layers train or not, or even if we should allow the training of only some intercalated layers.

To get the weights and biases from the output layer using Keras we can use the following method:

```py
# weights_training[0] = layer weights
# weights_training[1] = layer biases
weights_training = model.layers[-1].get_weights()
```

Now you should specify the weights for the new output layer. You can use, for example, the mean of the weights for the weights of the new classes. It's up to you.

To set the weights and biases of the new output layer using Keras we can use the following method:

```py
model_2.layers[-1].set_weights(weights_re_training)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
model.pop()

base_model_layers = model.output
pred = Dense(11, activation='softmax')(base_model_layers)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=pred)
```

## Freeze the first layers, before train it

```
for layer in model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the problem is singlelabel-multiclass classification i.e. a sample will belong to only 1 of the 11 classes.

This answer will be completely based on implementing the way humans learn into machines. Hence, this will not provide you with a proper code of how to do that but it will tell you what to do and you will be able to easily implement it in keras.

How does a human child learn when you teach him new things? At first, we ask him to forget the old and learn the new. This does not actually mean that the old learning is useless but it means that for the time while he is learning the new, the old knowledge should not interfere as it will confuse the brain. So, the child will only learn the new for sometime.

But the problem here is, things are related. Suppose, the child learned C programming language and then learned compilers. There is a relation between compilers and programming language. The child cannot master computer science if he learns these subjects separately, right? At this point we introduce the term 'intelligence'.

The kid who understands that there is a relation between the things he learned before and the things he learned now is 'intelligent'. And the kid who finds the actual relation between the two things is 'smart'. (Going deep into this is off-topic)

What I am trying to say is:

- Make the model learn the new class separately.
- And then, make the model find a relation between the previously learned classes and the new class.

To do this, you need to train two different models:

1. The model which learns to classify on the new class: this model will be a binary classifier. It predicts a 1 if the sample belongs to class 11 and 0 if it doesn't. Now, you already have the training data for samples belonging to class 11 but you might not have data for the samples which doesn't belong to class 11. For this, you can randomly select samples which belong to classes 1 to 10. But note that the ratio of samples belonging to class 11 to that not belonging to class 11 must be 1:1 in order to train the model properly. That means, 50% of the samples must belong to class 11.
2. Now, you have two separate models: the one which predicts class 1-10 and one which predicts class 11. Now, concatenate the outputs of (the 2nd last layers) these two models with a newly created Dense layer with 11 nodes and let the whole model retrain itself adjusting the weights of pretrained two models and learning new weights of the dense layer. Keep the learning rate low.

The final model is the third model which is a combination of two models (without last Dense layer) + a new Dense layer.

Thank you..