# Retrain existing built keras cnn sequential model(predicting 16 categories) with more categories

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Below is the code to create the model and then saving it local directory. here all images are placed in local labelled folder. Now I want to add more images in different labelled folders and include them to this model. So overall, instead of retraining model from scratch I want to increment new label

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def readTestData(testDir):
data = []
filenames = []
# loop over the input images
images = os.listdir(testDir)
for imageFileName in images:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    imageFullPath = os.path.join(testDir, imageFileName)
    #print(imageFullPath)
    img = load_img(imageFullPath)
    arr = img_to_array(img)  # Numpy array with shape (...,..,3)
    arr = cv2.resize(arr, (HEIGHT,WIDTH)) 
    data.append(arr)
    filenames.append(imageFileName)
    return data, filenames
 def createModel():
    #model = Sequential()
    #model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
    #model.add(Activation("relu"))
    #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    #model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
    #model.add(Activation("relu"))
    #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    #model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(Dense(500))
    #model.add(Activation("relu"))
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=22))
    #model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    model = load_model('test')
    model.pop()
    model.pop()
    for layer in model.layers:
     layer.trainable = False
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=24,name='new_Dense',activation='softmax'))

    opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics= 
["accuracy"])
    return model    

random.seed(10)

X, Y = readTrainData("labelled images directory path")
# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
X = np.array(X, dtype="float") / 255.0
Y = np.array(Y)
# convert the labels from integers to vectors
Y =  to_categorical(Y, num_classes=22)

(trainX, valX, trainY, valY) = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.10, 
 random_state=10)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1, \
height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,\
horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the model
model = createModel()

# train the network
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS), \
validation_data=(valX, valY), \
steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, samples_per_epoch=len(trainX) * 
5,epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

# save the model to disk
model.save("test_new")
```

Comment: Can you show some code providing some information on what you already have and what you tried ?

Comment: I have added code for more clarity , can you pls help me how to add more labels in existing model.

Comment: Ok thanks, make sure you define all the variables in your code example. I for example added the correct imports and added the indentation to make it more ready to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you probably want to do is to remove the last 2 layers, which correspond to an output dimension of 22, and add the 2 new layers corresponding to the new output dimension (the same but with a different dimension for the `Dense` layer).

You can then refit your model on new data, if you want just to have a nice initialization. However, if you want to "freeze" the weights of your model and only fine-tune the last layers, you will need to set all the layers of your model as non trainable and then recompile the model:

```py
# these lines will remove the last 2 layers
model.pop()
model.pop() 
# do the following 2 lines only if you want to keep the weights from the first training
for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
model.add(Dense(output_dim=new_output_dim))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
# do the following 2 lines only if you want to keep the weights from the first training
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics= 
["accuracy"])
```

Comment: I couldnot understand how to keep weights with above mentioned code , I was referring another link and here they have provided another way for weights:- weights_training = model.layers[-1].get_weights() . Link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498608/how-add-new-class-in-saved-keras-sequential-model. Is there any blog/url where I can get complete code how to add new layers to existing model.

Comment: You just need to add similar lines to your code and then train with your new dataset.

Also you don't need to get the weights here because you have the model already at hand, or maybe I didn't understand something about your question.

Comment: I need to predict previous labels also along with new added ones, so do I need to get previous weights and add them to new model?

Comment: If you use what I showed you in my method, you are still using the same base model so you don't need to worry about the weights. This code snippet would just be at the end of the code you are showing in your question.

Comment: I used your approach and was getting below error :-
ValueError: The name "dense_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
ValueError: The name "activation_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
So replaced step model.add(Dense(output_dim=22)) with model.add(Dense(output_dim=24),name='new_Dense',activation='softmax')

I was able to create new model but it predicts only new categories for even old images that too with 54% of accuracy.
I have created a new training directory in my local with only these 2 new labels , is it wrong?

Comment: Hmm I didn't have this issue. Can you post the whole code here?
If you are fitting the model with only 2 categories it is going to output only those 2 no matter what you trained it on before.

Comment: With all images(old label and new label) in same directory worked fine for me. Thanks for yourall help!! . But new model which is trained with only 2 additional labels is created with size of 100MB and old model which was trained with 22 labels size is 300MB, is this fine?

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you are doing, without reproducible code it's very difficult. I couldn't answer your question precisely.

Comment: I have updated createmodel method where I am loading previously existing model "test" and then deleting last 2 layers . Here dimensions are increased from '22' to '24' . Now I have kept all new labelled images as well as old images under same directory which I am reading through "readTrainData" method. My new model created "test_new" is predicting correct output for previously as well new labelled images. But earlier model "test" size on local disk is 300MB and new model size is 100MB , so I am keen to know is this correct?

Comment: well in my case they are both the same size with 6.3MB. Note that I haven't trained them since you didn't give reproducible code (i.e. with the data reading function working).

Comment: In general have you seen size being reduced for retrained model?

Comment: No, there seems to be something fishy here.

Comment: I have added method to readTrainData also , can you please let me know what seems to be wrong here. Just to reiterate , I am keeping all images (new and old )in same folder. Only change I have done was in createModel method updating your code snippet.

Comment: No but without the data, the data reading function on its own is not useful (plus you have some undefined variables here). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to make the perfect minimal working example. Trying to come up with one will certainly help you answer this new question. If not I suggest opening a new question, because the topics are getting slightly mixed here. If my answer solved your initial problem please [upvote and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: FYI , I have tried to upvote your answer but getting "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Even though your answer was throwing some error on execution and I am still wondering why new model size is reduced , it had provided me closest hint how to retrain new model. So I have accepted it.